# What is the standard practice for starting a task with multiple parameters

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, task-parallel-library, pfx

Right now I have

```
class MyParamClass
{
   all the parameters I need to pass to the task
}

MyParamClass myParamObj = new MyParamClass();
myParamObj.FirstParam = xyz;
myParamObj.SecondParam = abc;
mytask = new Task<bool>(myMethod, myParamObj,_cancelToken);
mytask.Start()

bool myMethod(object passedMyParamObj)
{
   MyParamClass myParamObj = passedMyParamObj as MyParamClass;
  //phew! finally access to passed parameters
}
```

Is there anyway I can do this without having the need to create class MyParamClass ? How can I pass multiple params to a task without this jugglery ? Is this the standard practice ? thank you

Comment: what does the `pfx` have to do with the question ...just curious

Comment: Click this link and search for PFX http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_Extensions Am I missing something ? thanks

Comment: nope ...I didn't realize that PFX is comprised of *both* TPL and PLinq.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this with a lambda or inline delegate:

```
myTask = new Task<bool>(() => MyMethod(xyz, abc), _cancelToken);
```

Comment: that is much cleaner. I guess when I have a large number of params I will go with what I have and for a smaller list I will use your approach for readability. thanks

Comment: If your finding you have a lot of parameters I tend to try to refactor all the code for the task into another class as well, pass the params through the constructor or Properties and then have a DoWhateverAsync() that returns the Task.
Not always that easy to do, but usually worth a try.

Comment: This approach is easy to read, and it's convenient since it essentially is getting the compiler to build the param class for you behind the scenes.  Just be careful you don't get in trouble with access to modified closures, which is a risk your original approach didn't have.

Comment: Thanks Scott. "access to modified closures" was somethimg I had seen via Resharper before but not really understood. I see many articles online explaining this. Time for more coffee and reading.

Answer (score 6):

Using a wrapper class to handle is the standard way to do this. The only thing you can do otherwise is use a `Tuple` to avoid writing `MyParamClass`.

```
mytask = new Task(myMethod, Tuple.Create(xyz, abc), _cancelToken);
mytask.Start();

bool myMethod(object passedTuple)
{
     var myParamObj = passTuple as Tuple<int, string>;
}
```

Comment: Nice to know about tuple. Just read up on this. Upvoted. thanks